# javascript active class on page load menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have build a admin panel using Laravel ..Where I have side bar having multiple menus..
The problem I'm facing is whenever i click on one of the menu's I want to active that class But it couldn't keep that active.

Here is the code of my sidebar

```
<div id="sidebar">   
    <ul>
        <li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Members</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('member/create')}}">Create Member</a></li>          
              <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('member')}}">Member List</a></li>               
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Payroll</span></a>
            <ul>
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('payroll/create')}}">Create Monthly Payroll</a></li>               
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('managerPayroll')}}">Unapproved Monthly Payroll (Management)</a></li>                           
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('nonManagerPayroll')}}">Unapproved Monthly Payroll (Employee)</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('printEmployeeAccount')}}">Print Employee Account</a></li>                     
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Report</span></a>
            <ul>
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('serachManagerReport')}}">Search Manager Report</a></li> 
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('serachNonManagerReport')}}">Search Employee Report</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('salaryReport')}}">Salary Sheet </a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu-2"> <a href="{{asset('changePassword')}}"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Password Update</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And the javascript I've used to make the url as active.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>         
<script>
    (function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById('sidebar'),
        anchor = nav.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        current = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
        if(anchor[i].href == current) {
            anchor[i].className = "active";
        }
    }
})();
</script>
```

Can anyone suggest what's the Error here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in an easy way :
Add @yield in every menu in following way:

```
<li class="@yield('menu_create_member') submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('member/create')}}">Create Member</a></li>
```

For Main menu and sub menu try this :

```
<li class="@yield('menu_member') submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Members</span></a>
  <ul>
   <li class="@yield('menu_create_member') submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('member/create')}}">Create Member</a></li>                        
   </ul>
 </li>
```

Then add this in every page after extending master template `(@extends('layouts.master'))` when you load

```
@section('menu_member','active')  // For main menu


@section('menu_create_member','active') // For sub menu
```

And then automatically active current menu

Comment: Inside of Member Menu two submenu is there create and List. When I click on create yup submenu got active But it's Hide under the Main menu from your solution, Means submenu is active OK ..But it's inside of Main menu so I can't see where am I actually..Can you help me to sort that out please?

Answer (score 0):

Like this.use `$`.To load jquery.Or you can also use `$(document).ready(function(){});`

```js
$(function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById('sidebar'),
        anchor = nav.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        current = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
        if(anchor[i].href == current) {
            anchor[i].className = "active";
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">   
    <ul>
        <li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Members</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('member/create')}}">Create Member</a></li>          
              <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('member')}}">Member List</a></li>               
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Payroll</span></a>
            <ul>
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('payroll/create')}}">Create Monthly Payroll</a></li>               
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('managerPayroll')}}">Unapproved Monthly Payroll (Management)</a></li>                           
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('nonManagerPayroll')}}">Unapproved Monthly Payroll (Employee)</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('printEmployeeAccount')}}">Print Employee Account</a></li>                     
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Report</span></a>
            <ul>
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('serachManagerReport')}}">Search Manager Report</a></li> 
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('serachNonManagerReport')}}">Search Employee Report</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-2"><a href="{{asset('salaryReport')}}">Salary Sheet </a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu-2"> <a href="{{asset('changePassword')}}"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Password Update</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: I used this also..But it can't set the active class !

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping your code inside parentheses you are not calling the function inside.

```
(function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById('sidebar'),
        anchor = nav.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        current = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];

    for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
        if(anchor[i].href == current) {
            anchor[i].className = "active";
            break;
        }
    }
}) (); // Add 2 parentheses to call the anonymous function
```

PS.
I also added a break inside the for loop, since i guess you only need to make one link active per page

Comment: Try to print to js console the value of `var current` and if it matches any of the anchor's href. Remember that it must be an exact match